# Laplace transformation with imaginary unit $i$

Tags: laplace-transform

Does there exist a real-valued function $f(t)$ such that its Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}{f(t)}$ is an expression that contains the imaginary unit $i$?

For example
$$
\mathcal{L}(f(t))=\frac{1}{(-ip)^3+1}.
$$

I have not yet been able to find such an example, but on the other hand, in some technical applications, images of the Laplace transform arise that contain the imaginary unit $i$. And I don't know how to interpret this, as a mistake?

Comment: When computing Laplace transforms of real valued functions, $s$ designates a complex variable, so I don't see how this is possible if the function is real valued.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to interpret this: consider the Laplace transform
$$
\mathcal L\{f(t)\}(s) = \frac{1}{sp^3 + 1}
$$
Evaluating this expression at $s = -i$ gives the expression in your question. In other words, the Laplace transform is evaluated only on the imaginary axis. This corresponds to the Fourier transform.

Comment: I am assuming $p$ is meant to be the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)$ is real then $\overline{f(t)} = f(t)$.  Then
$$
\overline{F(s)} = \int_0^\infty \overline{f(t)\mathrm e^{-st}} \,\mathrm dt = \int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm e^{-\overline{s}t} \,\mathrm dt = F(\overline{s})
$$
So $F$ is real for real $s$.